# How do I migrate .NET Core 2.2 Web API to .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I was following [Microsoft's migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration), but failed. So, instead, I created a new project with .NET 2.2 to establish a clean template, and then tried migrating to .NET Core 3.0. But it once again failed. In the `Startup.cs`, the dependency injection cannot find the method `services.AddMvc()`.

It seems my code still refers to .NET 2.2 instead of .NET 3.0.

If I run `dotnet watch run`, I get the following error:

> Application startup exception System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'.
>   To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set
>   'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside
>   'ConfigureServices(...).    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, Action'1 configureRoutes)          at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at netmig.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env) in E:\testapp\netmig\Startup.cs:line 46    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) Unhandled exception.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint Routing does not support
>   'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc'
>   set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside
>   'ConfigureServices(...).    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, Action'1 configureRoutes)          at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at netmig.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env) in E:\testapp\netmig\Startup.cs:line 46    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
>   host, CancellationToken token)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
>   host, CancellationToken token)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
>   host)    at netmig.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   E:\testapp\netmig\Program.cs:line 18 watch : Exited with error code
>   -532462766

[The full code I am running can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/callmeblessed/netmig). My .NET info:

> dotnet --info .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:
>   3.0.100       Commit:    04339c3a26
>
> Runtime Environment:      OS Name:     Windows     OS Version: 
>   10.0.18362  OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 3.0.0   Commit:  7d57652f33
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: The error looks like it relates to middleware configuration. Check this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code

Comment: When you change version of Net you always have to do a clean build to get code to compiler properly.

Comment: @jdweng I did dotnet clean before and dotnet restore afterthat.

should i uninstall 2.2 to get this work?

Comment: You can have more than one version of Net Installed.  You could have VS2018 with Net Core 2.0 and VS2019 with Net Core 3.0.  The problem is the compiler dependencies do not work when Net changes.  You cannot have the obj files on a project mixed different versions of Net.  If you update to Net Core 3.0 all the obj files need to be compiled with Net Core 3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For v2.2

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And for v3

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Also make sure your csproj is target .net core 3.0

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: i tried this but it seems the project linked to netcore2.2

in my vscode, I cannot get services.AddControllers()

IWebHostEnvironment also unrecognized.

Comment: You can still use `AddMvc()` and `UseMvc()`. The new methods like `AddControllers()`, `UseEndpoints()` ,etc. are just if you want to be more granular