# Migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-3.0

We currently have an **ASP.NET Core** *2.2* web app that we would like to migrate to *3.1* (as it's newer and contains several enhancements). There are articles on migrating from *2.2* to *3.0* but not *2.2* to *3.1*.

Is the preferred migration route to upgrade to *3.0* first then upgrade to 3.1? There seem to be a lot of incompatibilities between *2.2* and the newer *3.0* / *3.1* frameworks.

Are there any best practices / general guidelines for upgrading an existing **ASP.NET Core** *2.2* web app to *3.0* / *3.1*?

Comment: The same articles apply in both cases. The breaking changes were introduced in 3.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to migrate dotnet core 2.2 webapi to dotnet core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114413/how-to-migrate-dotnet-core-2-2-webapi-to-dotnet-core-3-0)

Comment: @TonyNgo the OP asks if it's different to migrate to 3.1. The linked answer doesn't cover the overall migration either

Comment: @TonyNgo That article is related to a specific error message after upgrading to .NET Core 3.0. It seems that the upgrade path is to go from 2.2. to 3.0 first, then go from 3.0 to 3.01. This would seem to be the best approach.

Answer (score 5):

There is no official documents to directly migrate from 2.2 to 3.1.  Actually microsoft encourage migrate version by version.

Most break change are made when [migrate from 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), and [3.0 to 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) only have some config updates(you can easily tell that 3.0 to 3.1 migrate docs are much more shorter than 2.2 to 3.0). Mostly a package reference update and framework version update from 3.0 to 3.1.

Briefly speaking, if you are migrating from 2.2 to 3.1. accomplish 2.2 to 3.0 contributes 90% of the work you have to do, 3.0 to 3.1 just contributes 10% of the entire migration.  Major change between 3.0 and 3.1 are [SameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#react-to-samesite-cookie-changes) attribute.

Comment: So it looks like the preferred path is to upgrade from 2.2 to 3.0 first, then finally upgrade to 3.1.

Comment: That's true, and 3.0 to 3.1 you just have little work to do.