# Migrate from ASP.NET Core 1.0 directly to ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.8

We have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application that we want to migrate to the latest .NET core version (3.1 at the time of this post).However, Microsoft's official docs only show how to do the migration in steps, and quite a lot of them. We first have to upgrade to core 2.0, then to 2.1, 2.2 and so on, until we finally arrive to 3.1, and each step is very long a complicated. Is there a shortcut we can take to go directly to 3.1? Or perhaps two steps, like jumping to 2.2 and then to 3.1?
BTW, we are using the full .NET framework.

thanks,
ashilon

Comment: You could try jumping straight to 3.1 then just looking back through the instructions for each error you come across, to find the relevant parts that would solve that.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184327/migrating-from-asp-net-core-2-2-to-3-1),as `Elendil Zheng-MSFT` says 'microsoft encourage migrate version by version.'